# Automatically underline rows in excel based on unique data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I frequently use a spreadsheet, onto which we put a table of data.

The data is actually several rows per item we would be dealing with, but the number of rows changes.

For example, several items will all be listed with the **same order number**. What I then have to do is go through and **underline** the rows (bottom border) when it **changes** into a new order.

Is there a more convenient way to highlight a section of the table, then have an **entire row** formatted with the bottom border everytime a new value is found in a column?

Comment: Conditional Formatting will do what you want with a formula that compares the cell in the column to the one below it, if they do not match then put the line.

Comment: Do you need the formatting change to be permanent (like, if the data is copied elsewhere or broken up)? The solution will vary depending on this. Conditional Formatting, Filtering, Subtotals, or a macro are all possible solutions.

Comment: It doesn't havew to do anything complicated, as long as the change in order number is marked by a border the data will just sit there from then on.